# Complex regular expression to match Strings shorter than n characters

Tags: java, regex

I have the following Java regular expression:

```
^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(?:_[A-Z0-9]+)*$
```

I want to extend the above regex to match only Strings which are between 1 and 32 characters in length.

I have tried using groups and the `{n,m}` operator, but that didn't work because I have the `*` operator twice. My feeling is that there could be a a solution using zero-width negative lookahead?

Comment: So what's the point of the non-capturing group here?

Comment: @skamazin I don't need to capture anything, but I don't want two underscores in a row.

Comment: What's wrong with `.length()`? Way faster than regExpr.

Comment: People always seem to have this problem when asking a question: they ask what's wrong with their solution without presenting the actual *goal*. How can we properly guess what the RegEx is supposed to do if it has a problem? Please make an edit so that a proper answer may be posted.

Comment: It's for a piece of third-party software that accepts Java regexes in its config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead:

```
^(?=.{1,32}$)[A-Z][A-Z0-9]*(?:_[A-Z0-9]+)*$
```

This is the same as your regex, but ensures that the whole string is between 1 and 32 characters long.

Comment: Hmm, this won't work with unicode characters I think